# Can't upload APNs in Firebase Cloud Messaging Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't upload APNs auth key in Firebase Cloud Messaging console. "Upload" button is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I get it now, after a series of tries, you must have 'owner' role for you to upload APNs. Mine was 'editor' only so I can't upload.

Comment: Thank you, i had the same problem